# Inline asm: push function parameters

Tags: c++, assembly, parameters, inline-assembly

I'm having problems calling C++ functions from inline assembly. I need to push the required parameter on the stack, but something is going wrong. If I push `3`, for example, then everything works fine, but if I try to push the value of a variable (from the function) or `[ebp+8]` (same thing), it is incorrectly received as `1` by the called function, regardless of the actual value.

```
int i;

DWORD nietgebruikt(DWORD x)
{
    // x is always 1
    x += 40;
    return x;
}

_declspec(naked) void asmfunc(DWORD x)
{
    _asm
    {
        push    x; // or [ebp+8]
        call    nietgebruikt
        pop x // or [ebp+8]

        add i,  eax
        ret
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    i = 1;

    asmfunc(3);

    cout << i << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you declare the function as naked, then you are responsible for setting up the ebp register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried stepping through your code under the debugger, to visualize and understand its execution?  You'll probably find that quite useful in the long run.

More specifically, your `_tmain` function is passing the value `3` into `asmfunc` *by value*, not *by reference*. In other words, any updates made by `asmfunc` to its local "copy" of the integer will not be seen by the calling function.

You might consider having your `asmfunc` try returning the updated value instead, and then display that value in `_tmain`.